# mysql-real-escape-string: Access denied in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am trying to sanatize the input using mysql-real-escape-string before i save the data into my database using CakePHP. And i get the following error

> mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access
>   denied for user 'nobody'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

My Code:

```
public function admin_videos($id = null) {
        if(!($this->isLogged() && $this->isAuthorized())) {
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => true));
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->request->data['MovieVideo']['video'] = mysql_real_escape_string($this->request->data['MovieVideo']['video']);
            $this->request->data['MovieTrailer']['video'] = mysql_real_escape_string($this->request->data['MovieTrailer']['video']);
            if ($this->Movie->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The movie has been saved', 'admin/flash_success');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The movie could not be saved. Please, try again.', 'admin/flash_error');
            }
        } else {
          $this->request->data = $this->Movie->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Movie.id' => $id), 'contain' => array('MovieTrailer', 'MovieVideo')));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note:

A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string() otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and FALSE is returned. If link_identifier isn't defined, the last MySQL connection is used.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is not needed for CakePHP when using ORM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/view/153/Data-Sanitization):

> CakePHP already protects you against SQL Injection if you use CakePHP's ORM methods (such as find() and save()) and proper array notation (ie. array('field' => $value)) instead of raw SQL.

So forget about manually calling `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: i am trying to add Youtube Video Code into my database. So i dont need to use that ?

Comment: The ORM layer of cake already takes care of protecting you from sqli attacks.

Comment: If you _are_ in a situation where you have to bypass the ORM layer and manually sanitize data (such as complex find conditions), you can make use of Sanitize::escape($value, $connection) or $Model->getDataSource()->value($value)

Comment: There are cases where you need to build complex SQL query manually and escape input before executing.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you haven't connected to the mysql db.
Try mysql_connect() and mysql_select_db() with the correct credentials

Answer (score 2):

In case of complex queries manually constructed `Sanitize::escape()` for CakePHP 2.x or for CakePHP 3.x

```
    $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    $clean_string = $connection->quote('dirty"string--%/\');
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql_real_escape_string() requires a connection to a database as the second parameter unless you've already opened a connection:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

You can try one the following:

- Try using mysql_escape_string (which is now deprecated)
- Switch to PDO and use the quote function ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php )
- Initialise a connection to your database first, and pass that connection to mysql_real_escape_string

Generally I would recommend using PDO as it's better OO, and is more supported than the mysql_* functions